# Proof of $\frac{\Gamma(k+b)}{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(b+1)} = \frac{k^b}{\Gamma(b+1)}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac1k\right)\right)$

Tags: combinatorics, gamma-function

How to show 
$$\frac{\Gamma(k+b)}{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(b+1)} = \frac{k^b}{\Gamma(b+1)}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac1k\right)\right),$$
where $b \in [0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Some mention of context is welcome when asking Questions here.  It not only helps Readers respond expeditiously in a useful way, it avoids the appearance of asking about problems which are not yet digested. The motivation for the Question, the approach(es) already tried, and any difficulty encountered are all suitable material to add context.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I do agree. I'll keep that in mind now onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint:

Multiply both sides by $\Gamma(b+1)$.

By Stirling's approximation:

$$\Gamma(x+1)={\sqrt {2\pi x}}\left({\frac {x}{e}}\right)^{x}\left(1+\mathcal O\left({\frac {1}{x}}\right)\right)$$

And by binomial expansion:

$$(x+y)^n=x^n+nyx^{n-1}+\mathcal O(y^2x^{n-2})$$

Comment: Thanks. However, I did not get the use of binomial expansion. Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: @Rohit In the Stirling's approximation, I come up with some binomials and thought it might be of use there.  Though I note that you could just bootstrap this by using the fact that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ to make the gamma function go to infinity, making Stirling's approximation better?

Comment: @Rohit Also, is the $\mathcal O(1/x)$ supposed to be as $x\to\infty$ or $x\to0$?

Comment: Okay. One more question if you don't mind: The expression I wanted to prove suggests that $\frac{\Gamma(k+b)}{\Gamma(k)} > k^b$. But numerically, I found that $\frac{\Gamma(k+b)}{\Gamma(k)} < k^b$. How is it possible?

Comment: @Rohit A [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/icofmcraf8) so we can see this more easily?

Comment: It looks like $\frac{\Gamma(k+b)}{\Gamma(k)} > k^b$ due to multiplication by $(1 + O(1/k))$ on the right hand side. But the graph shows that $\frac{\Gamma(k+b)}{\Gamma(k)} < k^b$ when $b \in (0,1]$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rohit I updated the graph.  If you want lower and upper bounds, they're there.  And I'm going to bet this is due to inequalities with Stirling's approximations.

Comment: @Rohit Note that $1>1-1/x=1+\mathcal O(1/x)$  This is most likely the case.

Comment: Oh, okay. I literally took $1 + O(1/x) > 1$. Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit No problem, and I hope you found the upper and lower bounds useful: $$(k+b-1)^b<\Gamma(k+b)/\Gamma(k)<k^b\ \forall\ k>0,b\in[0,1)$$

Comment: Yeah. In fact, they are quite helpful in a bigger picture of the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @Rohil btw, I noticed that this is for $b\in[0,1)$ because the exponential part of Stirling's doesn't grow fast.

Comment: And the [new graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/swhrrag9hm).  @Rohit

Comment: As per the new graph, as $k \to \infty$, $(k + b -1)^b \sim k^b$. Right?

Comment: @Rohil take the ratio of the two and apply binomial expansion for something better.

Comment: Thanks. If you afford to spend some time to look at one more problem I faced, please have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068941/show-that-sum-n-1-infty-k-choose-nb-1-choose-n-1xn-b-frac-k.

Comment: I think no need. Using the upper bound provided by you, I can proceed to solve the problem in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068941/show-that-sum-n-1-infty-k-choose-nb-1-choose-n-1xn-b-frac-k.

Comment: @Rohit oh, well, glad to help.